# converting into html form to pdf

Tags: html, jsp

I am making my student admission form like student name,mobile,phone number, father name etc etc. I have 2 tables of 10 rows and 6 columns
the details entered in the by the new student is shown in proper form in next page (example- design  html page how original form looks like). Now i want to save it as a pdf.

I applied the code but it shows error.

Code

```
String s="";
try{
    String ref=request.getHeader("referer");
    URL url = new URL(ref);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
      s=s+line;
    }

    Document doc=new Document(PageSize.A5.rotate());
    File f=new File("C:\\Users\\DILJEET\\Desktop\\data111.pdf");

    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\DILJEET\\Desktop\\data111.pdf"));

    doc.open();

    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(s));

    doc.close();

    reader.close();   
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

---

Error

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8084/finalproject/fillfeedbackformaction.jsp
```

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println(e);` do `e.printStackTrace()` and add the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: Still showing the same error..Java IO exception response code 500 error...